# Expiration date for a Windows Phone in-app product purchase?

Tags: in-app-purchase, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to create an in-app product purchase for a Windows Phone 8 app, which automatically expires after a period of time? When using the Windows Phone dashboard to create the in-app product, there doesn't seem to be a way to set an expiration time (for example 6 months, 15 days etc) but on the other hand the [ProductLicense-class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.productlicense.aspx) contains an [ExpirationDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.productlicense.expirationdate.aspx) -property.

Is the property just a leftover from the Windows 8 apps or is there a way to set an expiration date for a Windows Phone 8 in-app purchase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ProductLicense.ExpirationDate isn't supported on WP8. It's there for Win8 API compatability.

> **Windows Phone 8**
>
> This API is not implemented and will throw an exception if called.

See @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.applicationmodel.store.productlicense.expirationdate.aspx